# Missed semicolon occurs during React packaging process

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, build

I am using Create React App to create my app and I am using scss in the app however, I have translated the scss to css through vscode plugin but still I am getting an error when I run `npm run build`.
The error message is as follows

``

> react-qitoj@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.a79b553d.css from Css Minimizer plugin
mymac/react-qitoj/static/css/main.a79b553d.css:653:25: Missed semicolon [webpack://. /src/index.scss:684,20][static/css/main.a79b553d.css:653,25]
``.

How do I fix it.

I've tried updating the Css Minimizer plugin and removing scss to no avail.

Comment: Why would you convert SCSS to CSS with a plugin? CRA has built-in support for SASS, you just have to [install the dependency](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/).

Comment: I tried to compile scss directly using sass, but it has the same problem.
```
error processing CSS
  file:/src/index.scss:25:4: missing semicolon
You tried to parse SCSS using the standard CSS parser; try again using the postcss-scss parser.
  You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser.
```
and the scss code that reported the error is
```
 --boxShadow: bos-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 10px 15px -3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 6px -2px;
``.
I don't know how I should fix it。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the SCSS file mentioned in the error message, src/index.scss in your code editor. **Go to line 684** (or the area around it) to identify the missing semicolon.

In SCSS, it's common to use semicolons at the end of each rule or declaration. Make sure that there is a semicolon at the end of the statement that's causing the issue.

For example, if you have code like this:

```
.my-class {
  color: red
}
```

You should add a semicolon at the end of color:

```
.my-class {
  color: red;
}
```

Recompile the SCSS and rebuild the your react app again using:

```
npm run build
```

**Cache Issue:**
If you still encounter the error even after fixing the SCSS, try clearing the build cache before running the build again. You can do this with the following command:

```
rm -rf node_modules/.cache
```

Then, run **npm run build** once more.

Hopefully it will solve your problem!

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it didn't work for him.

Comment: OK,I find it,I have a formatting error.

Comment: Great! you are good to go.